# How To Access FileZilla Remotely?

Tags: networking, ftp, portforwarding, filezilla

I've Created My Own FileZilla FTP server and I wanted to access it from my local Network. 
So I've done that. but there are Two Problems I'm Facing right now.

**Problem 1:- Can't connect ON PC which is connected with same Router But with LAN**

My father's PC is connected with LAN And My Laptop is Connected with WiFi 
So over WiFi with Any Device I can connect to my Server but when I try to connect my FTP to my father's PC (which is connected on LAN and with same Router)
I can't connect it

**Problem 2:- Can't connect it Remotely**

I want to access my this FTP server with Internet so that I can connect it with Remotely. I've referred  on so many websites. but Can't Find a complete step by step Tutorial... I've Configured my FTP but still Can't connect it with Internet for remote access.. plzz help me out.

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** As you say wifi-connected devices can access the server, so there are different cases you shall check, as where my experience reaches, these two might be the reasons:

- Is client/network isolation enabled in your router's wifi settings? This can be checked and solved by accessing your router's management console.
- Is your father's PC on a different subnet (XXX.XXX.**SUBNET**.XXX)? If so, you have two choices, changing all devices' subnet masks to 255.255.0.0 (This might be applicable in your router's DHCP settings too.), or changing your father's PC's IP address to match the local subnet.

**Problem 2:** This has two solutions, both need resources that might not be worth it, but yet:

- Connect to a virtual private network on the cloud (VPN), this way, your PC will become a part of a private network. You can connect other devices from other networks which can access the VPN server to the private network, so your PC and the device will now be in a same network like in your home network.
- Some ISPs provide static IP addresses or internet plans with static IPs. Check if the internet plan you use is so, if not, you might be able to rent an IP address from them. With static IPs your network can be accessed from the internet. Anyway there might be a bit of effort needed to ensure that your PC is accessed in the first place.

And just letting you know, this question must be moved to the [Super-User Forums](https://superuser.com/).